# Why do I keep getting column name is ambiguous for a left join on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EdocodeDB2;
USE EdocodeDB2;

-- create
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  IdNum int,
  Name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(IdNum)
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'Kosuke');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'Keisuke');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (3, 'Icchy');

CREATE TABLE INSURANCE (
  IdInsurance int,
  Name varchar(255),
  Employee_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY(IdInsurance)
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO INSURANCE
VALUES (1, 'CAR', 1);

INSERT INTO INSURANCE
VALUES (2, 'CAR', 3);

-- left join
SELECT IdNum, Name
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE
ON EMPLOYEE.IdNum = INSURANCE.Employee_id;
```

Column 'Name' in field list is ambiguous but I'm clearly saying `FROM EMPLOYEE`

I had to change the `Id` field to `IdNum` and `IdInsurance`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two columns called `Name`, one in table `EMPLOYEE`, the other in table `INSURANCE`.
How does MySQL know which table you want to get the column from?

You should specify the table names to clear up the ambiguity:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.IdNum, INSURANCE.Name -- Or EMPLOYEE.Name if you mean the column in the EMPLOYEE table
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE
ON EMPLOYEE.IdNum = INSURANCE.Employee_id;
```

"*but I'm clearly saying `FROM EMPLOYEE`*" - That's not how MySQL works. The first table in the `FROM` clause doesn't automatically imply which instance of the columns you're referring to. When there's a column with the same name in multiple tables in the `FROM` / `JOIN` clauses, then the table name (or an alias of that table) must be explicitly specified in the `SELECT` clause. It's also good practice to do so anyway, so someone who sees your query immediately knows which table each column belongs to.

Comment: Thanks!  I got what I wanted using your command and adding a few columns: `create table MajorTable2 as
SELECT EMPLOYEE.IdNum, EMPLOYEE.NameEmp,
INSURANCE.IdInsurance, INSURANCE.NameInsurance FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN INSURANCE
ON EMPLOYEE.IdNum = INSURANCE.Employee_id;`